# Do I need to downgrade my conda version in order to install a module?

Tags: python, installation, conda, version, miniconda

I install new modules via the following command in my miniconda

```
conda install -c conda-forge axelrod
```

It tries to resolve but says i have not the right conda version.

```
Collecting package metadata (current_repodata.json): done
Solving environment: failed with initial frozen solve. Retrying with flexible solve.
Solving environment: failed with repodata from current_repodata.json, will retry with next repodata source.

ResolvePackageNotFound:
  - conda==4.10.3
```

Therefore i hit

```
conda --version
```

which returns **conda 4.11.0**

output of `conda list`

```
# Name                    Version                   Build  Channel
anyio                     3.3.3            py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
argon2-cffi               21.1.0           py39hb82d6ee_0    conda-forge
async_generator           1.10                       py_0    conda-forge
attrs                     21.2.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
babel                     2.9.1              pyh44b312d_0    conda-forge
backcall                  0.2.0              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
backports                 1.0                        py_2    conda-forge
backports.functools_lru_cache 1.6.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
beautifulsoup4            4.10.0             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
bleach                    4.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
brotli                    1.0.9                h8ffe710_6    conda-forge
brotli-bin                1.0.9                h8ffe710_6    conda-forge
brotlipy                  0.7.0           py39hb82d6ee_1001    conda-forge
ca-certificates           2021.10.8            h5b45459_0    conda-forge
certifi                   2021.10.8        py39hcbf5309_1    conda-forge
cffi                      1.14.6           py39h0878f49_1    conda-forge
chardet                   4.0.0            py39hcbf5309_1    conda-forge
charset-normalizer        2.0.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
colorama                  0.4.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
conda                     4.11.0           py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
conda-package-handling    1.7.3            py39hb3671d1_0    conda-forge
cryptography              3.4.8            py39hd8d06c1_0    conda-forge
cycler                    0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
datefinder                0.7.1              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
dateparser                1.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
debugpy                   1.4.1            py39h415ef7b_0    conda-forge
decorator                 5.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
defusedxml                0.7.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
entrypoints               0.3             pyhd8ed1ab_1003    conda-forge
et_xmlfile                1.0.1                   py_1001    conda-forge
exiftool                  12.30           pl5321h57928b3_1    conda-forge
fonttools                 4.28.5           py39hb82d6ee_0    conda-forge
freeglut                  3.2.1                h0e60522_2    conda-forge
freetype                  2.10.4               h546665d_1    conda-forge
icu                       68.1                 h0e60522_0    conda-forge
idna                      3.1                pyhd3deb0d_0    conda-forge
importlib-metadata        4.8.1            py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
intel-openmp              2021.4.0          h57928b3_3556    conda-forge
ipykernel                 6.4.1            py39h832f523_0    conda-forge
ipython                   7.28.0           py39h832f523_0    conda-forge
ipython_genutils          0.2.0                      py_1    conda-forge
jasper                    2.0.33               h77af90b_0    conda-forge
jbig                      2.1               h8d14728_2003    conda-forge
jedi                      0.18.0           py39hcbf5309_2    conda-forge
jinja2                    3.0.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jpeg                      9d                   h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
json5                     0.9.5              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jsonschema                4.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_client            7.0.6              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyter_core              4.8.1            py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
jupyter_server            1.11.1             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab                3.2.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_pygments       0.1.2              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
jupyterlab_server         2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
kiwisolver                1.3.2            py39h2e07f2f_1    conda-forge
lcms2                     2.12                 h2a16943_0    conda-forge
lerc                      3.0                  h0e60522_0    conda-forge
libblas                   3.9.0              12_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libbrotlicommon           1.0.9                h8ffe710_6    conda-forge
libbrotlidec              1.0.9                h8ffe710_6    conda-forge
libbrotlienc              1.0.9                h8ffe710_6    conda-forge
libcblas                  3.9.0              12_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libclang                  11.1.0          default_h5c34c98_1    conda-forge
libdeflate                1.8                  h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
liblapack                 3.9.0              12_win64_mkl    conda-forge
liblapacke                3.9.0              12_win64_mkl    conda-forge
libopencv                 4.5.3            py39h4b6fd43_5    conda-forge
libpng                    1.6.37               h1d00b33_2    conda-forge
libprotobuf               3.18.1               h7755175_0    conda-forge
libsodium                 1.0.18               h8d14728_1    conda-forge
libtiff                   4.3.0                hd413186_2    conda-forge
libwebp-base              1.2.1                h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
libzlib                   1.2.11            h8ffe710_1013    conda-forge
lz4-c                     1.9.3                h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
markupsafe                2.0.1            py39hb82d6ee_0    conda-forge
matplotlib                3.5.1            py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-base           3.5.1            py39h581301d_0    conda-forge
matplotlib-inline         0.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
menuinst                  1.4.18           py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
miniforge_console_shortcut 1.0                  h57928b3_0    conda-forge
mistune                   0.8.4           py39hb82d6ee_1004    conda-forge
mkl                       2021.4.0           h0e2418a_729    conda-forge
munkres                   1.1.4              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
nbclassic                 0.3.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbclient                  0.5.4              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nbconvert                 6.2.0            py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
nbformat                  5.1.3              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
nest-asyncio              1.5.1              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
notebook                  6.4.4              pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
numpy                     1.21.2           py39h6635163_0    conda-forge
olefile                   0.46               pyh9f0ad1d_1    conda-forge
opencv                    4.5.3            py39hcbf5309_5    conda-forge
openjpeg                  2.4.0                hb211442_1    conda-forge
openpyxl                  3.0.9              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
openssl                   1.1.1l               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
packaging                 21.0               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pandas                    1.3.3            py39h2e25243_0    conda-forge
pandoc                    2.14.2               h8ffe710_0    conda-forge
pandocfilters             1.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
parso                     0.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pdfminer                  20191125           pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
perl                      5.32.1.1        1_h57928b3_strawberry    conda-forge
pickleshare               0.7.5                   py_1003    conda-forge
pillow                    8.3.2            py39h916092e_0    conda-forge
pip                       21.3               pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prometheus_client         0.11.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
prompt-toolkit            3.0.20             pyha770c72_0    conda-forge
py-opencv                 4.5.3            py39h832f523_5    conda-forge
pycosat                   0.6.3           py39hb82d6ee_1006    conda-forge
pycparser                 2.20               pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
pycryptodome              3.11.0           py39hb82d6ee_0    conda-forge
pygments                  2.10.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyopenssl                 21.0.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pyparsing                 2.4.7              pyh9f0ad1d_0    conda-forge
pyqt                      5.12.3           py39hcbf5309_8    conda-forge
pyqt-impl                 5.12.3           py39h415ef7b_8    conda-forge
pyqt5-sip                 4.19.18          py39h415ef7b_8    conda-forge
pyqtchart                 5.12             py39h415ef7b_8    conda-forge
pyqtwebengine             5.12.1           py39h415ef7b_8    conda-forge
pyrsistent                0.17.3           py39hb82d6ee_2    conda-forge
pysocks                   1.7.1            py39hcbf5309_3    conda-forge
pytesseract               0.3.8              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python                    3.9.7           h7840368_3_cpython    conda-forge
python-dateutil           2.8.2              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python-tzdata             2021.4             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
python_abi                3.9                      2_cp39    conda-forge
pytz                      2021.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
pytz-deprecation-shim     0.1.0.post0      py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
pywin32                   301              py39hb82d6ee_0    conda-forge
pywinpty                  1.1.4            py39h99910a6_0    conda-forge
pyzmq                     22.3.0           py39he46f08e_0    conda-forge
qt                        5.12.9               h5909a2a_4    conda-forge
regex                     2021.10.23       py39hb82d6ee_0    conda-forge
requests                  2.26.0             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
requests-unixsocket       0.2.0                      py_0    conda-forge
ruamel_yaml               0.15.80         py39hb82d6ee_1004    conda-forge
send2trash                1.8.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
setuptools                58.2.0           py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
six                       1.16.0             pyh6c4a22f_0    conda-forge
sniffio                   1.2.0            py39hcbf5309_1    conda-forge
soupsieve                 2.3                pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
sqlite                    3.36.0               h8ffe710_2    conda-forge
tbb                       2021.3.0             h2d74725_0    conda-forge
terminado                 0.12.1           py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
testpath                  0.5.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tk                        8.6.11               h8ffe710_1    conda-forge
tornado                   6.1              py39hb82d6ee_1    conda-forge
tqdm                      4.62.3             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
traitlets                 5.1.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
tzdata                    2021c                he74cb21_0    conda-forge
tzlocal                   4.0.1            py39hcbf5309_0    conda-forge
ucrt                      10.0.20348.0         h57928b3_0    conda-forge
urllib3                   1.26.7             pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
vc                        14.2                 hb210afc_5    conda-forge
vs2015_runtime            14.29.30037          h902a5da_5    conda-forge
wcwidth                   0.2.5              pyh9f0ad1d_2    conda-forge
webencodings              0.5.1                      py_1    conda-forge
websocket-client          0.57.0           py39hcbf5309_4    conda-forge
wheel                     0.37.0             pyhd8ed1ab_1    conda-forge
win_inet_pton             1.1.0            py39hcbf5309_2    conda-forge
winpty                    0.4.3                         4    conda-forge
xz                        5.2.5                h62dcd97_1    conda-forge
yaml                      0.2.5                he774522_0    conda-forge
zeromq                    4.3.4                h0e60522_1    conda-forge
zipp                      3.6.0              pyhd8ed1ab_0    conda-forge
zlib                      1.2.11            h8ffe710_1013    conda-forge
zstd                      1.5.0                h6255e5f_0    conda-forge
```

Comment: Those errors tend to be red herrings, unfortunately. Could you post the output of `conda list`?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider creating a separate environment, e.g.,

```bash
conda create --name foo -c conda-forge axelrod
```

The **base** environment is where the `conda` package lives and it should reign supreme there. That is, one shouldn't ever need to downgrade it for the sake of anything else. Generally, I recommend that users should not use the **base** environment for work.